# To get the path of file in a project in vb

Tags: .net, vb.net, file-io

I am running windows application in vb.net.I have a xml file named mail.xml in folder named XmlFiles.In default.aspx.vb i have to get the path of mail.xml.What code i hve to write to make it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the GetFullPath static method of the Path class:

```
Dim fileName As string = "myfile.ext"
Dim path1 As string = "mydir"
Dim path2 As string = "\mydir"
Dim fullPath As string

fullPath = Path.GetFullPath(path1)
Console.WriteLine("GetFullPath('{0}') returns '{1}'", _
    path1, fullPath)

fullPath = Path.GetFullPath(fileName)
Console.WriteLine("GetFullPath('{0}') returns '{1}'", _
    fileName, fullPath)

fullPath = Path.GetFullPath(path2)
Console.WriteLine("GetFullPath('{0}') returns '{1}'", _
    path2, fullPath)

' Output is based on your current directory, except
' in the last case, where it is based on the root drive
' GetFullPath('mydir') returns 'C:\temp\Demo\mydir'
' GetFullPath('myfile.ext') returns 'C:\temp\Demo\myfile.ext'
' GetFullPath('\mydir') returns 'C:\mydir'
```

Example is from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath(VS.80).aspx).

Another way is to use the fullName property of the FileInfo class (inherited from FileSystemInfo), see usage below:

```
Sub DisplayFileSystemInfoAttributes(ByVal fsi As FileInfo)
    ' Assume that this entry is a file.
    Dim entryType As String = "File"

    ' Determine if this entry is really a directory.
    If fsi.Attributes = FileAttributes.Directory Then
        entryType = "Directory"
    End If

    ' Show this entry's type, name, and creation date.
    Console.WriteLine("{0} entry {1} was created on {2:D}", _
        entryType, **fsi.FullName**, fsi.CreationTime)
End Sub
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.fullname.aspx) as well.